# Installation attempt using pip3 results in "Temporary failure in name resolution" exceptions

Tags: dns, display-resolution, pip

I am attempting to install an RF tool called QSpectrumAnalyzer on Ubuntu 16.04 from Github.  My workstation is connected to the internet through a company proxy server, which (I believe) is configured properly in Ubuntu.  The instructions for installing QSpectrumAnalyzer on the Github page are:

```
# Add SoapySDR PPA to your system
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:myriadrf/drivers

# Update list of packages
sudo apt-get update

# Install basic dependencies
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-pyqt5 python3-numpy python3-scipy soapysdr python3-soapysdr

# Install SoapySDR drivers for your hardware (e.g. RTL-SDR, Airspy, HackRF, LimeSDR, etc.)
sudo apt-get install soapysdr-module-rtlsdr soapysdr-module-airspy soapysdr-module-hackrf soapysdr-module-lms7

# Install QSpectrumAnalyzer locally for your current user
pip3 install --user qspectrumanalyzer
```

After adding the Myriad-RF repository, every package installed successfully.  However, when I attempt to run the pip3 installation, it throws three exceptions.  Apologies in advance for this being so long:

```
pip3 install --user qspectrumanalyzer
Collecting qspectrumanalyzer
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-noneany.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 137, in _new_conn
     (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 67, in create_connection
     for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 560, in urlopen
     body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
     self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 787, in _validate_conn
     conn.connect()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 217, in connect
     conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 146, in _new_conn
     self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fccf164ad30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
     status = self.run(options, args)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 328, in run
     wb.build(autobuilding=True)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 748, in build
     self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 360, in prepare_files
     ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 512, in _prepare_file
     finder, self.upgrade, require_hashes)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 273, in populate_link
     self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 442, in find_requirement
     all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 400, in find_all_candidates
     for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 545, in _get_pages
     page = self._get_page(location)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 648, in _get_page
     return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 757, in get_page
     "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
   File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
     return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 378, in request
     return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
   File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
   File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
     resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
   File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 376, in send
     timeout=timeout
   File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 610, in urlopen
     _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
   File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 228, in increment
     total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

I assume the two "Temporary failure in name resolution" errors are a rather important clue, but I don't know where the name resolution is breaking down.  I don't have any problems installing packages with apt-get from other Launchpad repos, so I don't understand the resolution issues.  On a side note, I am also seeing almost identical exceptions when I attempt to install Universal Radio Hacker using pip3 as well.  After doing some searching, I added 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 as other DNS servers, but it did not change the results.

The aggravating part is that I installed this for a customer a couple weeks ago on an **IDENTICAL** system, and didn't have any problems.  So I know for a fact that this installation works.  Of course, I no longer have access to that system, otherwise I would have just cloned the drive and been done with it.

While I can kind of follow Python code, I am not a coder, so my knowledge in that realm is limited.  And while I've been working with Red Hat for a long time, I am pretty much a noob on Ubuntu.

If anyone has an idea where I could look or what I might be missing, I'm all ears.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Temporary failure in name resolution" generally means a DNS issue.

Comment: Yes, but what kind of issue?  The machine is pulling DNS info from the DHCP server.  I don't have any problems browsing or pulling down packages from the web.

Answer (score 2):

I've added

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

to file:

```
/etc/resolv.conf
```

And it solved for me the issue.

Answer (score 1):

After all of this, it ended up being a DNS issue on the proxy server, which I don't administrate.  Once it was resolved, everything installed properly.